# Error en archivo .yaml.Configuración de red con netplan

Tags: linux, redes

Les explico mi problema. Tengo un servidor ubuntu 20.04 sin interfaz gráfica.
El servidor consta de dos tarjetas de red, una en modo NAT para dar salida de internet al exterior, y otra en modo de red interna para proveer internet a los clientes.
Para aclarar algunos incisos,  se esta operando mediante máquinas virtuales VM.
El archivo de configuración de las dos tarjetas de red es el siguiente:
[image: Configuración con netplan]

El problema está en que no coge esta configuración el servidor, ya que al ejecutar el comando:

> ip a

Se muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: SOLUCIONADO ! El problema es que ubuntu 20.04 no realiza conexión netplan. Hice lo mismo en ubuntu 22.04 y funciona!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la versión de [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu). Sólo se realizan conexiones netplan a partir de la versión 22.04.